# What are the rules to compose f-algebras in a catamorphism

Tags: haskell, recursion-schemes

Here are some simple F-algebras for lists. They work with the `cata` function from the 
[recursion-schemes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes) library.

```
import Data.Functor.Foldable

algFilterSmall :: ListF Int [Int] -> [Int]
algFilterSmall Nil = [] 
algFilterSmall (Cons x xs) = if x >= 10 then (x:xs) else xs

algFilterBig :: ListF Int [Int] -> [Int]
algFilterBig Nil = [] 
algFilterBig (Cons x xs) = if x < 100 then (x:xs) else xs

algDouble :: ListF Int [Int] -> [Int]
algDouble Nil = [] 
algDouble (Cons x xs) = 2*x : xs

algTripple :: ListF Int [Int] -> [Int]
algTripple Nil = [] 
algTripple (Cons x xs) = 3*x : xs
```

Now I compose them:

```
doubleAndTripple :: [Int] -> [Int]
doubleAndTripple = cata $ algTripple . project . algDouble
-- >>> doubleAndTripple [200,300,20,30,2,3]
-- [1200,1800,120,180,12,18]
```

`doubleAndTriple` works as expected. Both algebras are *structure preserving*, they don't 
change the length of the list, so cata can apply both algebras to every item of the list.

Next one is filter and double:

```
filterAndDouble :: [Int] -> [Int] 
filterAndDouble = cata $ algDouble . project . algFilterBig
-- >>> filterAndDouble [200,300,20,30,2,3]
-- [160,60,4,6]
```

It doesn't work properly. I assume it's because `algFilterBig` is not structure preserving.

Now the last example:

```
filterBoth :: [Int] -> [Int] 
filterBoth = cata $ algFilterSmall . project . algFilterBig 
-- >>> filterBoth [200,300,20,30,2,3]
-- [20,30]
```

Here both algebras are not structure preserving, but this example is working.

What are the exact rules for composing f-algebras?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Structure preserving algebras" can be formalized as natural transformations (that can be between different functors).

```
inList :: ListF a [a] -> [a]
inList Nil = []
inList (Cons a as) = a : as

ntDouble, ntTriple :: forall a. ListF Int a -> ListF Int a
algDouble = inList . ntDouble
algTriple = inList . ntTriple
```

Then, for any algebra `f` and natural transformation `n`,

```
cata (f . inList . n) = cata f . cata n
```

The `doubleAndTriple` example is an instance of that for `f = algTriple` and `n = ntDouble`.

This doesn't easily generalize to larger classes of algebras.

I think the case of filter is easier to see without categories, as a consequence of the fact that `filter` is a semigroup homomorphism: `filter p . filter q = filter (liftA2 (&&) p q)`.

---

I searched for a general but sufficient condition for a "distributive law" on filter-like algebras. Abbreviate a bit `afs = algFilterSmall`, `afb = algFilterBig`. We reason backwards, to find a sufficient condition for:

```
cata (afs . project . afb) = cata afs . cata afb  -- Equation (0)
```

By definition of a catamorphism, `z = cata (afs . project . afb)` is the unique solution to this equation (a disguised commutative diagram):

```
z . inList = afs . project . afb . fmap z
```

Substitute `z` with the RHS of the previous equation:

```
cata afs . cata afb . inList = afs . project . afb . fmap (cata afs . cata afb)
-- (1), equivalent to (0)
```

- On the LHS, we apply the definition of `cata` as a Haskell function, `cata afb = afb . fmap (cata afb) . project`, and simplify with `project . inList = id`;
- on the RHS, we apply a functor law `fmap (f . g) = fmap f . fmap g`.

This yields:

```
cata afs . afb . fmap (cata afb) = afs . project . afb . fmap (cata afs) . fmap (cata afb)
-- (2), equivalent to (1)
```

We "cosimplify" away the last factor `fmap (cata afb)` (remember that we are reasoning backwards):

```
cata afs . afb = afs . project . afb . fmap (cata afs)  -- (3), implies (2)
```

This is the simplest one I could come up with.

Comment: Your `inList` is called `embed` in the library (it's a method of the `Corecursive` class).

Comment: @Li-yao Thanks. The first part with the Natural Transformation is fine. This reasoning is also valid for non-list catamorphisms. However with the filters I have not yet any criterias other than these natural transformations, when composing f-algebras for non-list data structures (eg expression trees) are possible.

Comment: @Jogger I expanded my answer with a criterion that you may find interesting.

Comment: In Haskell, `filter` is actually a homomorphism to the dual semigroup: `filter p . filter q = filter (liftA2 (&&) q p)`. In particular, `filter (const undefined) . filter (const False) = filter (const False)`. Apparently, failing to swap these led to a bug in the `filter` rewrite rules in the early days of GHC!

Comment: Good catch! That's an interesting observation.

Comment: I don't know if I'd have noticed it if I hadn't read the relevant comment in `GHC.List` years ago.

Comment: @Li-yao Thanks for elaborating the additional "filter"-explanation